# Perforce Streams: Selective Copy up to Main

Tags: configuration, perforce, perforce-stream

We utilize streams to manage our code in Perforce.  We are having issues when efforts are moved out to later releases as part of our controls requires that we have a valid/approved artifact tied to a release before we copy up to the main stream and proceed to cut the release stream.

In Perforce when you are copying code up from a development stream to the main stream is there a way to deselect change lists?  When I attempt it, it appears I can deselect specific change lists, usually the last few added, but Perforce seems to not allow certain lists to be deselected, I am guessing if the file changes are included in later changes to the same file.

Is there a good way to selectively move these change sets?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the merge command instead of copy in this case to cherry pick the changes up to main. Copy takes files at a point in time and makes the target look like the source no matter what. Merge will let you pick around changes that aren't ready.